# Using font-awesome as HTML content

Tags: css, font-awesome

I need to be able to use font-awesome as HTML content.

So instead of using the `:before` selector in css and doing something like this:

```
.wysihtml5-command.blockquote:before { content: "\f10d"; }
```

I need to actually use it inside HTML tags like this:

`<a class="someclassWithFontawesomeAsFont">\f10d</a>`

But this does not work.

Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Comment: `\f10d` is only for the css content declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put Font Awesome classes inside an `<i>` tag

```
<a href=""><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
```